# Project Builds and Runs, but does not Archive

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I have a project which builds and runs fine on the simulator and device, but fails when archiving.

The project is very old, but I have created a separate component which I have added in the workspace.

The main project is written in Objective-C, the new project is written in Swift 4. The project also uses CocoaPods and also includes another subproject written in Swift 3.2

There are various errors which all boil down to the same thing, the sub project is not producing any output when it is compiled. OR it is just not compiled. I see no errors in the code itself, just when trying to reference it:

```
//1
error: /Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<id>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<app name>/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Framework.framework: No such file or directory`

//2
Signing Identity:     "iPhone Developer: <redacted>“

/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<id>/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ ArchiveIntermediates/<app name>/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<app name>/Frameworks/<framework>.framework: No such file or directory
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

//3
@import ModuleName;

Module ‘ModuleName’ not found
```

Here’s what I’ve tried:

- Clear derived data
- Restart Mac
- Add `$(SRCROOT)` to Main Target > Build Settings > Framework Search Paths > Release
- Confirmed project is present in Embedded Binaries
- Confirmed project is present in Linked Frameworks and Libraries
- Removing and re-adding project to embedded binaries and frameworks and libraries
- Removing the import declaration
- I am opening the workspace and not the project
- `Skip install` set to `YES` in Subproject build settings
- Comparing build settings from the working sub project with the failing one (they are the same)
- Running `pod update`
- Changing `Always Embed Standard Swift Libraries` makes no difference either way

Other notes:

- In `/Users/<user>/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<id>/Build/ Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/<app name>/  InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/<app name>.app/Frameworks/` there is    a .framework file for the other sub project and all the pods, but not for this one
- In `podfile`, `use_frameworks!` is present

Update:

After running an archive today I am only seeing the error:

```
Module 'ModuleName' not found
```

The other errors are gone

Comment: In your podfile, do you have `use_frameworks!` enabled? There's also a related setting for `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries` in your debug/release configs

Comment: Thanks @NIckSchneble I've updated the question with the answers to your points

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The issue was to do with the `iOS Deployment Target` setting:

- The main project: iOS 10
- Sub project: iOS 11

In `Debug` it is building only for the current architecture, in `Release` it builds for all. Obvious once you know.

Setting the sub project to build for iOS 10 fixed the issue.

The most frustrating part: I double checked the build log and it doesn't mention the version issue anywhere :(

Comment: I know this is against SO policies, but thanks Lewis. You saved my skin today.

Comment: Thank you !! Your comment also helped me save a lot of time !

Comment: MY GOD. This was it! In my podfile, I had given deployment target as iOS 12 and in the project iOS 10. 

THANK YOU!

Comment: AWESOME AWESOME AWESOME.. one of my PODs was targeting iOS 11 and my deployment target was iOS 10. Thank you so much. I have learnt another way of debugging.

Comment: I signed into my stackoverflow account just to give this a thumbs up. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 15):

It's impossible to tell what exactly causing it to fail archiving. BUT I'm pretty sure I can give you the correct direction =]

Running on simulator or even a real device - compiles the project for "**Debug**"

Archiving tough, compiles for "**Release**"

I bet that if you set that running on simulator will compile on Release mode, it will fail!

[image: Screenshot of xCode Run configuration]

Check it!!

If I correct you just need to set some of the `Build Settings` for **Release** to match **Debug**

My first guess is: All the search paths (**Framework search path**, and **Runpath search path**)

I saw a similar behavior [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6399)

> I got it to archive after all.
>
> It looked like the SDK-Project was missing a build configuration
> Adhoc. Which Project used to archive the project for a specific build
> scheme. I think the compiler was looking for modules in the
> $(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME) path

Comment: You are correct that changing this did cause the build to fail on the device and it gave me faith that there was a fix to this issue. Thanks so much!

Comment: I am writing up the answer now. I gave you the reputation :)

Comment: I had the same issue, and ultimately this was the key for me: my original project had 3 configurations: Debug, Release and Distro, and I had added a framework that only happened to have 2 configs: Debug and Release. So I added the Distro config to my framework and then it worked!

Comment: Changing did produce the same error. But in my case, everything matched on both release and debug. Am still stuck. :(

Just figured out the issue.. one of my PODs was targeting iOS 11 and my deployment target was iOS 10. Thank you so much. I have learnt another way of debugging.

Comment: Same issue as Mwangi. Podfile platform :ios, '11', but Xcode target build settings had 'iOS Deployment Target' was 10.0.

Setting iOS Deployment Target to 11 in Xcode fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was having this error, and while my deployment targets did not match, that wasn't actually the fix for me. I had added a new build configuration that I was trying to use for my archive, but I forgot to run `pod install` after adding it. After running `pod install`, I was able to archive my app just fine, even though the deployment targets for some of the Pods are iOS 10 while the main app target is iOS 11.

Answer (score 1):

Might be not relevant to you, but helpful to others:
If you using multi-modular SwiftPM-based architecture, then you should read errors carefully and find out if some of your package targets import some other one in sources without integrating it in the `Package.swift` file. In this case, even the release build will resolve dependencies somehow and succeed if some other package contains your dependency, but the archive will fail.

Package graph examples:

––––––––––

```swift
App
├– PackageA [target1(import PackageC.target1)]
└– PackageB [target1(import PackageC.target1)]
   └– PackageC [target1]
```

*Builds with success, archives with errors (Can't find module PackageC.target1 in PackageA.target1)*

––––––––––

```swift
App
├– PackageA [target1(import PackageC.target1)]
|  └– PackageC [target1]
└– PackageB [target1(import PackageC.target1)]
   └– PackageC [target1]
```

*Builds and archives with success*

Answer (score 1):

## Cocoapods and Architecture settings

I had a Podfile that set `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` to `arm64` in a post-install script and this was consistent with my main target. This setting was ok for building on Debug mode (x86_64) but didn't work for release building (Archives). I realised the script set `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` for the Pod targets even on physical devices (Any iOS SDK) rather than only on Simulators.

## Steps

1. I ran `pod deintegrate`.
2. I deleted Derived Data.
3. I deleted `Podfile.lock` (now we have a fresh start).
4. I updated the Podfile iOS version to be the lowest supported version in each Pod.
5. Refactor `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` script.

#### Refactoring `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` script

I refactored:

```
config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS'] = 'arm64'
```

from the Podfile post-install script to the following:

```
   post_install do |installer|
     installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
         ...
         config.build_settings['EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]'] = 'arm64'
       end
     end
   end
```

I haven't done watchOS here because it wasn't a watchOS app, however, we need to do this for **all** supported simulated device targets.

6. I left `EXCLUDED_ARCHS` to `arm64` to `Any iOS Simulator SDK` in the main target for Release mode in the main target. The same logic here applies to other sims.
7. `pod install`
8. Archive again. :D