# Certificates and provisioning Profile confusion Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I have a bit of confusion about the whole certificate and Provisioning Profile file system.

I finally started to look into beta testing my app, and I'm trying Firebase App distribution but I'm not succeeding, my friends can't download my app..

The first time I exported the .ipa as Developer, and after adding this device UUIDs to my devices in my dev account I re exported the .ipa that now should run on their devices.. It still doesn't.
So I realised that I should have use "adHoc" instead of "Developer" so I did go through the archiving again and this time it asked me to create a distribution certificate which I then downloaded (a .p12 file and a .cer file)..

Now my doubt is:
In Xcode preferences/account I can see both the developer and the distribution certificates, but the project's Provisioning Profile says 1 certificate, meaning only the developer one right? 
Can it be the reason why my testers (friends for now) can't download the app?

What should I do to use an update profile? In my dev account there is no profiles generated..

Where I'm mistaking in the whole process?
As always thank you very much for you time and help.

Comment: check inside xcode how many devices exist in the provisioning profile. you'll likely see zero devices despite your uploading the UUIDs to your developer account. this is a problem and there's not an easy solution other than manually downloading the new provisioning profile from your dev account and then manually installing it and uninstalling it until it registers with Xcode. the better way is to skip using Firebase for this feature and just use TestFlight. TestFlight works perfectly fine for what you're doing.

Comment: but when you're exporting the .ipa one phase is generating the certificate a provisioning by connecting to Apple..shouldn't be using all my registered devices than?

Comment: sure, but go into xcode and where it shows your certificates, click the "?"  or "!" button next to where it says "provisioning profile" and see if it includes devices, if you don't see that it shows devices included, then that's your problem. this is a persistent problem with Apple developer acct syncing with Xcode.

Comment: Yeah.. only one certificate shown but 0 devices.. not even 1..

Comment: but on my developer account I se no profiles.. shall I just create one than?

Comment: yep, you'll have to do that, yes. and as i said before, this is a mess to do, it's much easier to just use TestFlight and let Xcode manage the certificates automatically. doing what you're doing is going to crush you in the future since it's such a massive waste of time to get the provisioning profiles working right every time you add a new device.

Comment: I'm trying this just to test the app quickly , without the validation process .. I will of course use TestFlight and go through that, but I thought I give a shot to the new service..and I'm regretting it already hahah..

Comment: lol, the time yo've spent working on this trying to get it to work in Firebase, it wold have already been approved, the approval for test flight is simple. they literally only make sure they can get past the log in screen, but i get it. mess around with the provisiongin profiles and see how that works out.

Comment: The reason I thought it would be more difficult than what you just described has to do with Privacy policy and those kind of thing.. Don't they fuss about in TestFlight approval?
Actually in the beginning I thought the my problem was the deployment target.. being in Xcode at iOS 11.0 and their devices already updated tu 12 and 13..lol

Comment: nah, do this, set up a simple Word Press website with two routes: /privacy and /terms, then use a free service like this to make terms and privacy policy in 2 minutes and then copy and paste into a blog post and you're done.https://termsandconditionstemplate.com/privacy-policy-generator/  you can even do this for a production app. i have many times to get the app out ahead of the web design.

Comment: Sweet I'll do that. Thank you so much..so you just have tgive Apple the links , I understood that they should be put inside the app.. and I really didn't wanna waste time now on that..

Comment: yep, no problem, good luck

Comment: Thank you , cheers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201394/discussion-between-vincenzo-and-loxx).