# Firebase App Distribution - "Waiting for developer" message

Tags: ios, firebase, continuous-delivery, app-distribution, firebase-app-distribution

I'm developing an iOS application and using App Distribution to distribute my test releases to QA Team, I didn't had any problem before, everything was smooth and pretty (estrange considering iOS development hehe)... but recently I face a problem that I can't resolve and I didn't found any documentation about it.

I constantly adds new Testing devices to the project (as the QA team grows) and follow the same steps...

- Adds the new account to my tester list in Firebase.
- Get the register attempt with the UDID of the new device.
- Register the new device UDID in the Apple Developer Console
- Distribute a new release of the app through App Distribution.
- Install the certificate in the device
- And voila, download the new distribution.

But this case is different... because in this iPhone XS Max with the latest iOS version, the download button never appears, and we just can see the following message: "**Waiting for developer**".

I try a lot of different solutions, redownload and import the Profile, to redistribute the app, create new profiles, force new devices in Fastlane, delete and readd the UDID in developer console... dammit... I create new certificates in my rage hahaha... but the problem persist, anyone face this problem before?

## Update

I sent a ticket to Firebase support center, and they told me that the UDID wasn't in the distribution profile, so my solution was recreate the profile, because download and import the ad-hoc profile didn't work.

This issue isn't a Firebase problem, it was a classic issue related to iOS signing hell.

Comment: I suggest contacting Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson. I already do that, when Support answers me I'll update the question with their answer.

Comment: I was also have same issue, it got resolved try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58262038/testers-could-not-download-app-from-firebase-app-distribution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem when tried to add device for Firebase Testing.
I made all instructions from Firebase troubleshooting.

> If you're installing an Ad Hoc distribution, the Waiting for developer
> button appears when the developer hasn't yet configured their app to
> run on your test device. To make their app available to you, the
> developer must complete the following steps:
>
> - Add the test device's UDID in the Apple Developer portal (the UDID is    emailed to the developer when you register the device to
>   Firebase).
> - Include the device in the app's provisioning profile.
> - Build the app using the updated provisioning profile.
> - Distribute the new build using the Firebase console, the CLI, or    fastlane.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/troubleshooting?platform=ios#waiting-dev-ios

Than I noticed that all of my provision files (for me it was folder /Users/user/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles) not include UDID of new device. Every file can be previewed if you will choose view mode or right click on it, select "Get Info" and expand "Preview" block. If you will scroll to bottom you will see block "PROVISIONED DEVICES" with codes of your devices.
For me the problem solved when I found files which descriptions had "IOS Team Provisioning Profile: my.bundle.name" and "Developer Profile Name: my.bundle.name" ("Developer Profile Name" is profile name which you see in your Profiles list at https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/profiles/list).

1. I moved 2 files (which descriptions started from "IOS Team Provisioning Profile: my.bundle.name" and "Developer Profile Name: my.bundle.name") from /Users/user/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles to another folder (I was afraid to lose it and not removed, just moved)
2. Opened XCode
3. Selected menu XCode -> Preferences
4. Selected Accounts
5. Chose my e-mail account name
6. Selected MyTeamName and clicked button "Download Manual Profiles"
7. Selected my Personal Profile and clicked button "Download Manual Profiles"

After it in the folder "Provisioning Profiles" appeared two new provision files and I found the name of my device in the bottom of their descriptions.
Than i cleaned project rebuild app-file and distributed it on test and all worked.