# Can not create archive in Xcode but can build project

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, archive, xcode11

I can build my project and deploy to an iOS device but I can't create an archive to upload to TestFlight

[image: Xcode build error only when creating archive]

```
ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked framework 'iDENProtectFramework'
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_KeystoreBridge", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iDENtearSocketPeripheral.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_IDTBridge", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iDENtearSDK.o
      objc-class-ref in iDENtearSocketPeripheral.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have frameworks project linked in General- Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Project Builds and Runs, but does not Archive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528818/project-builds-and-runs-but-does-not-archive)

Answer (score 0):

I went though all the projects and targets at set them to the same iOS 13 and arm64
changed the POD Project build settings Build Active Architecture only to yes
I could create an archive after that.

for some odd reason the Pod Project where set to x86 and not arm64. They build before and I have not changed that so not sure what's going on there? is that just the default for pods?