# Xcode Project Run on Device but failed to archive

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, build

I am working on an app, the app is running on iPhone perfectly, but whenever I tried to make build for Archive (to upload on TestFlight) it failed. I found [this question with no accepted/solution answer](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/690907?login=true&page=1#715745022) and I am also facing the same issue for my pods (my pods are different from the question pods) in

pod file

`can not find type'Binding" in scope.`

`unknown attribute 'ObservedObject'`

`Cannot find '_observable' in scope`

I cannot update my pods for some reason but for testing purpose

I tried (update my pod) with no success on the bug.

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47528818/project-builds-and-runs-but-does-not-archive) wit no success.
I remove my all pods and reintegrate them with no success.
I tried this [article](https://khushwanttanwar.medium.com/xcode-12-compilation-errors-while-running-with-ios-14-simulators-5731c91326e9) but it does not helped with `Xcode Version 13.4.1 (13F100)`

Image attached for my errors

[image: Image attached for my errors]

its same like the question I found on apple developer site and I attached that question above statement.

Normally I archive with option `Any iOS Device (arm64)` and for this app it's failing always.(Perfectly working for other apps).
So I tried to archive with the selection of iPhone and it also failed.

Kindly guide me how to solve this problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my own problem with the help of if condition. I added this line at the top of file

```
#if !(os(iOS) && (arch(i386) || arch(arm)))
```

and at the end of file

```
#endif
```

This peace of code solved my problem, and now I am able to build my app for the TestFlight.